# How to highlight the right item in the navbar

Tags: menus, navigation

In my site i have a navbar which is created by using the new feature of wordpress 3 - "the menus ".In my site this navbar conatins both categories and pages.

When I'm in a single post / sub-page , the navbar doesn't give the parent category /page  the class of "current-menu-item" and therefore that  item in the navbar  is not highlighted.

I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/how-to-get-current-cat-in-navbar-in-single-post/2010#2010)  but it really doesn't help me because the menu is not built on

category_ID  like a regualr  navbar created by wp_categories_list(), but on item_ID , which I don't understand how is generated.

I would like to know either how the  item_ID is generated, and/or how to highlight the right item in the navbar

Here is a printscreen of my navbar's HTML

[image]

and here is a printscreen of navbar created by wp_categories_list()

[image]

thanks!!

Comment: Is the current-menu-item or current-page-item class not what you're looking for?

Comment: You are seeking to highlight the top most parent element when the current page is direct descendent, correct? I'd like to know this answer to. OT: I wish WP did not add all those 'menu-item menu-item type-post_type' redundant classes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter you need is **nav_menu_css_classes**. You should be able to test for *in_category* on single post and archive pages, and add the appropriate class there.

Comment: That feeling when I find my own answer from two years ago, and its wrong. Ugh. The filter is actually named **nav_menu_css_class**.

Answer (score 1):

You can style this classes,

"current-cat"
"current-menu-item"
"current-page-item"