# Show nav link highlighted

Tags: custom-taxonomy, navigation

OK so i have a main menu and a sub-menu

How can i make a menu item active when viewing a single post.

The sub-menu uses taxonomies so i know i need to make the taxonomy active when one of the posts has the taxonomy in use

Comment: What does the main menu show?

Comment: shows home movies music sub-menu for movies is action adventure drama etc and music is rock hiphop country metal etc

Comment: but i need the sub menu highlited not the main. i already have code in place when viewing the sub-menu items but need to code when a post is active

Comment: So can anyone else help me

Comment: Could you show the code with which you create the sub menu that shows the the taxonomies? And another thing - if a post has more than one tag, you want all the tags that it has to be highlighted?

Comment: Well since the code is through WordPress nav menu setup its pretty basic. I did no coding on that part the only coding i did was jquery and css not html or php. Since i only plan on showing one unique tag in the nav bar then no just highlight that one tag. I have my tags setup Action, Adventure etc if it is both of those then there is a new tag Action-Adventure

Comment: I had to do something similar, but with the menu showing categories instead of taxonomies. If you want, I can show you the code (it's a function I added to functions.php, and hooked this way: `add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'current_type_nav_class', 10, 2 );` ), but you will have to convert the get_the_category() function to one that gets the post's taxonomy.

Comment: let's see what yeah got

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight nav menu terms](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17535/highlight-nav-menu-terms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i ended up doing some jquery and lots of it. The downside is that i have to add the code each time i create a new menu. I am looking into re-creating this but do not want to bother with it right now. [This is the link to the solution.](http://pastebin.com/bWC7a1ej) It is very very temporary so if you wish to use it go ahead but there are better ways. You may be able to hook into the wp_nav_menu classes and add a active class to the current active item and then use some jquery to finish it off.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar with highlighting current category in navbar, you can see my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/how-to-get-current-cat-in-navbar-in-single-post/2010#2010). The hook of course won't work for you, I think a better hook would be 'nav_menu_css_class'

Comment: Sorry i havent been able to try this yet. I have had some other problems happen with my site and they need priority. When i get a change ill post back.

Comment: I dont think this is going to work as there are some things that are for categories and i tried changing them out and that did not work

Comment: I could not get it to work but i did use this on another project. So ill mark as answered

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx - thank you, that's very kind of you. Although it might be misleading to mark as answered a question that you still need an answer for... Maybe just up upvote (if you want)? Or nothing?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the slug and and the current taxonomy against one another.

For example if you were outputting a menu using `get_terms($taxonomy)` you could use an if statement to check whether the current page's taxonomy is the same as the slug menu item and give it an active class.

```
            <?
                $taxonomy = 'disciplines';
                $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
                $current_taxonomy = get_query_var($wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy']);
                foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {

                    if ($current_taxonomy == $tax_term->slug) {
                        $active = 'active';
                    }

                    echo '<li class="filter ' . $active . ' clearfix"><a href="/disciplines/' . $tax_term->slug . '"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><i class="fa fa-circle"></i> ' . $tax_term->name . '</a></li>';

                    $active = "";
                }
            ?>
```

Where discipline is your custom taxonomy.

Answer (score -1):

have a read of this codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Dynamic_Menu_Highlighting

Comment: Have read it but will not do what i want. The default core setup highlights categories not tags

Comment: Link only answers contribute nothing. Besides, link is now dead.