# Highlight nav menu terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, navigation, filters

OK so i have `custom post types` and `custom taxonomies`. I have a sub-menu that is made of the custom taxonomies.

#### Example:

**registered taxonomy:** *Movies*

and

**terms:** *action*, *adventures*, *etc*. (= menu items)

#### Problem:

Now **I need to add a *highlight*-class** to the terms when the currently displayed page is an archive of one of the terms.

I am almost looking to use my nav menu as a breadcrumb so to speak.

Comment: This "sub menu" is created with the new custom navigation menu functionality of WordPress 3.0?

Comment: yes I am using the the new menu system

Comment: I would love to see an automated vs. of this. I looked at the pastebin code example below, but that would be a nightmare to maintain on a huge site. Has anyone attempted this yet?

Comment: As this is just recent, i dont think someone has tried this. I have been taking some spare time to see if i can do this but since i have other things more important than this; it will be a while before i finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So instead of pasting the code here ill just link to it since i do not feel like adding the code format to each line. This is most likely just temporary but will get what i need done. It is used with some of jquery scripting but should not need it. Feel free to edit as you wish and update this question with your re-writes
http://pastebin.com/bWC7a1ej

Comment: on a side note i do want to thank @JanFabry , @rarst, @kaiser, @toscho for helping me figure this out. Though i can say this is not how they would write it up i can assure you that