# has_term if/echo else/echo function

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus

ok so i have a nav menu with the top level of menu items being static pages. When you highlight or visit one of them there is a sub-menu that pops up. Each one of them has there own sub-menu and each sub-menu is full of custom taxonomy terms. Since WordPress will only give the current-menu-item class on an archive page i need to either add my own class or just add some custom css to show and highlight the term parent when viewing a single item.

My problem is I had the code working but then it quit working. See the code below

```
<? 
$has_news = has_term('news');
if ($has_news)
    echo '<style type=text/css>#navbar{display:block}';
else
    echo '';
?>
```

---

This is related to one of my other questions but I figured it would best be suite under its own with different tags.

***Related Question:*** [Highlight nav menu terms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17535/highlight-nav-menu-terms)

*wpversion: 3.1.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you'd need to pass a `$post->ID` in order to not `return false.`

Better use `is_object_in_taxonomy($object_type, $taxonomy)` and fill both the term and the tax in the function. It returns `(boolean)`, so simply add your class based on the result:

```
echo $class = is_object_in_taxonomy( 'news', 'your_taxonomy' ) ? 'current-whatever' : '';

// or: (simplified for readabilities sake:

// set empty and override only in case.
// So you avoid dropping errors if the condition was not met and $current not set.
$class = '';
if ( is_object_in_taxonomy( 'news', 'your_taxonomy' ) )
    echo $class = 'current-whatever';
```

Comment: what is the `?` and what do i put in the  `: 'HERE';`

Comment: Short for `if/else`. Google for "short hand php". It simply means: `"The variable class get's filled: If the condition "object is in the taxonomy" (?=matches condition:) add 'current-whatever' to the var (:=else) add '' empty to it;"`

Comment: Ok i did not know there was short hand php

Comment: Only makes sense for short one liners. Else you can't read your code in a month anymore. Also avoid using this for questioning two different things, before setting a value.